# How check video moderation status api youtube v3

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-data-api

How can i check video heldForReview comments status?
I need check, if comments are heldForReview status.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doc:

Call the `commentThreads.list` method to retrieve comments for the channel or video. Set the moderationStatus parameter's value to **heldForReview**. The API response could be used to display a list of comments with an option for the channel owner to publish or reject each one.

Comment: Thx, but i still can't find way to check, if youtube video moderation comments on or off ?